# Print date from multiple elements in an array using Time.strptime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, strptime

I am trying to print out formatted dates using elements of an array within a hash map (`records_array["START_TIME_SEC"]`)

The first element of the array is: `records_hash["START_TIME_SEC"][0]` which equals: 1405583947

Printing the hardcoded time works just fine:
`Time.strptime('1405583947', '%s')` prints: 2014-07-17 07:59:07 +0000 (This is correct)

Next, setting the hardcoded time to a variable as a string works just fine:

```
stime = '1405583947'
Time.strptime(stime, '%s')
```

prints: 2014-07-17 07:59:07 +0000 (again, correct!)

If i pull a single time from the array and try to use it in Time.strptime it works just fine:

```
stime2 = records_array["START_TIME_SEC"][0].to_s
Time.strptime(stime2, '%s')
```

prints: 2014-07-17 07:59:07 +0000 (correct once again)

However, When trying to iterate through the array and print out the dates for all elements I get an error:

```
<% (0..@records_array.count).each do|i| %>
<tr class="post">   

    <td>
    <% stime = @records_hash["START_TIME_SEC"][i].to_s %>
    <%= Time.strptime(stime, '%s') %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Error:
invalid strptime format - `%s'

Comment: for starters you have an error in your iterator. you need `(0..(array.count - 1))` but the ruby way to do that is `@records_hash["START_TIME_SEC"].each { |x| ... }`

Comment: Also you are referring to `@records_array` and `@records_hash` are these both objects or is this a typo because your other code shows `@records_array["START_TIME_SEC"]`.

Comment: Array.count - 1 solved the problem. Wow, I feel so stupid for being stuck on this for so long. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, the @records_array["START_TIME_SEC"] is a typo, it should be @records_hash["START_TIME_SEC"]

Answer (score 0):

+1 to xlembouras' comment about using `@records_array.each { |x| ... }`
Also, it seems you are using **records_hash** on your snippet instead of **records_array**.
That might be the real issue there.